# For any integer x ≥ 2, $\frac{3x + 1} {2x} , $ rounds down to 1

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm not sure how to approach this.

Would I prove the contrapositive? that x<2 does not round down to 1? But then 1 does round down to 1. So it is false?

Comment: Please check the tag wikis before usage - [tag:logic] has a particular meaning.

Comment: Sure. Will do. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

The contrapositive of the statement has to do with integers for whom $(3x + 1) / (2x)$ does not round down to one all being less than $2$, so your attempt at the contrapositive is incorrect.

---

Notice that this simplifies to $\frac 3 2 + \frac{1}{2x}$, and that $2x$ is pretty large for the range of integers you are considering. So what can you conlude about where $\frac 3 2 + \frac{1}{2x}$ is, relative to $1$ and $2$?

Comment: It will never be greater than 7/4. Since when x = 2, that is the highest possible sum.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to show
is that
$3x+1 \ge 2x
$
(so that it rounds
to at least one)
and
$3x+1 < 4x
$
(so the fraction
is less than two).

The first inequality
is true for
$x \ge -1$
and the second
is true for
$x > 1$,
which proves what you want.